# Como pegar cookie já existente via javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-5, cookies

Em meu projeto tenho uma página que é *html*. E como meu projeto está em asp.net mvc, eu não consigo validar se o usuário está logado ou não porque essa página não é *razor*.

Pesquisando, achei o *javascript cookie*, que cria, lê e deleta *cookies*. Então basicamente, já tenho um *cookie* criado e o que eu queria era que o *javascript cookie* pegasse esse *cookie* fizesse uma validação pra ver se  existe o *cookie*, se não, redirecionar para a página de *login*.

Até agora tenho esse código:

```
  <script>
    function getCookie(cname) {
        var name = cname + "=";
        var ca = window.document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1);
            if (c.indexOf(name) != -1) return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
        return "";
    }
    function checkCookie() {
        var permissao = getCookie(".PermissionCookie");
        if (permissao == "") {
            alert("Oooops! Você não tem permissão!");
            window.location.replace("/Index/Autenticacao")

        }
    }

</script>
```

Mas não esta funcionando...

Lembrando que eu quero que essa verificação seja feita assim que a página seja carregada.

O que eu posso fazer pra que ele funcione ?

Comment: Não está funcionando porque não esta pegando o cookie que já tem na aplicação. Pelo servidor não sei porque a página é em html. A não ser por ajax.Eu estou chamando ela em um botão existente na página. Só que quando ele é clicado  nada acontece.

Comment: Você tem acesso ao código do site que você quer verificar logado? Não poderia fazer uma requisição AJAX/REST por meio de um javascript devolvendo um true/false?

Comment: @mgibsonbr isso mesmo. Eu queria que não se acessasse a página se não estiver logado, e rodrigopq se por ajax puder fazer esse tipo de verificação, por mim estaria otimo! O que importa pra mim é: se não estiver logado, não ter acesso a essa página html.

Comment: Eu não consigo reproduzir o seu problema... http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/xzn05t26/ Veja se o cookie *realmente* não está lá, e se o botão que você está clicando na página está realmente chamando o código desejado.

Comment: @mgibsonbr explicando: Eu tenho uma action de autenticação. E nela eu gero um cookie com as permissões e o Id do usuário. Então em páginas razor, eu consigo fazer essa verificação do que tem no cookie e mostrar pro usuário somente o que ele pode ter acesso. Mas em páginas HTML não tenho como fazer essa verificação do cookie por código c# igual se faz nas páginas razor. Ou se faz isso com javascript, ou ajax, se realmente puder ser usado.

Comment: Então o que eu quero fazer é o seguinte: ao carregar a página, o javascript verifica pra mim se tem algum cookie gerado, ou seja, se tem algum usuário logado na aplicação. E se CASO NÃO ESTIVER NENHUM USUÁRIO LOGADO, não deixe entrar na página, redirecionando para uma tela de login, que já tenho aqui. Ficou mais claro agora ?

Comment: Okaaay. Deixa eu ver aqui. E te aviso! E tentando aqui no seu fiddle. Ele da que eu não tenho permissão. Ou seja o que eu quero.

Comment: Agora estou com outro problema... Mesmo o usuário logado ele não consegue pegar o cookie. E fica redirecionando. :(. Vendo no console ele mostra que o cookie não tem nada. Ou seja: "". Do jeito que da o retorno na função getcookie.

Comment: Não consigo vê-lo no console do navegador. A única coisa que aparece é:  [""]. Ou seja, o que a função getcookie retorna. :(

Comment: É, estamos chegando em algum lugar... :) Eu não tenho certeza, mas isso poderia ser resultado de um cookie `HttpOnly` - que é trocado entre o servidor e o browser, mas que o JavaScript não acessa. [Isso poderia fazer com que os cookies parecessem vazios](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15914744/520779). Agora já é um questão de ASP.NET - que eu não conheço em nada - então receio que terá de ser outra pessoa a te ajudar... :(

Comment: @mgibsonbr será que usando AJAX, resolveria meu problema ? Se sim, você sabe usar ?

Comment: A parte cliente, sim, a parte do servidor, não. @rodrigogq gostaria de responder algo?

Comment: @ÉrikThiago precisa realmente ser HTML? Não tem como fazer um php simples pelo menos? Não é muito seguro fazer o que está fazendo. O mais fácil seria fazer uma requisição `$.get()` por jquery, mas basta ser programador para conseguir tirar essa porção do código e pronto, a página está visível.

Comment: Pior que sim. Porque se eu fizer da forma normal pelo asp.net mvc , ou seja, fazendo a cshtml, não funciona, pois uma página cshtml precisa ter uma action da onde tirar toda a logica. A não ser que essa página seja uma partial. Mas ainda não tentei. E mesmo, teria que ser uma cshtml...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para fazer uma requisição jquery em AJAX, crie um arquivo "verificaAcesso.js", ou algo do tipo e bota no include da sua página.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $.get("http://www.seusite.com.br/pagina.asp", function(data, status){
     alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
   });
 });
```

Nesta página sua, você substitui o `Page_Load` por um `Response.Write` com true/false (uma string mesmo) e pronto:

```
 string json = "{\"logado\":\"true\"}";
 Response.Clear();
 Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
 Response.Write(json);
 Response.End();
```

Os cookies me parecem um tanto complicados.
Você até pode retirar alguns deles, mas acho que o internet explorer vai ficar advertindo que seu site tem um componente ActiveX (javascript) tentando fazer algo suspeito. Não lembro em quais versões, mas se o usuário não aceitar, seu javascript vai ser inútil.

Já o jquery é melhor.

Se a sessão estiver caindo (o cara estiver muito tempo em várias páginas HTML) e ficar deslogando, o melhor é colocar um `<img href="http://www.seusite.com.br/img.gif" />` com um gif de 1px por 1px transparente... isso já deve bastar para manter a sessão ativa.

Ainda acho bem inseguro, mas não sei qual a situação do seu projeto como um todo.

Comment: Logicamente você não vai dar o `alert`, mas vai tomar a ação necessária quando estiver logado... ou deslogado! Tente deixar sua página inteira `hidden` e só dê um `show` quando tiver certeza que está ok.

Comment: nessa string json ai, eu colocaria em um bloco javascript ? E é tranquilo. Meu sistema não tem informações sensíveis não.

Comment: Sim, exato. No caso eu coloquei uma variavel chamada `logado`. Lá no seu jquery, no lugar do `alert`, você pode fazer uma verificação do tipo `if(data.logado) { ... } else { ... }`.

Comment: Entendi. Dai eu posso fazer somente o if. Então seria tipo: if(data.logado == null){aqui oredirect pra página de login}. Porque se o usuário estiver logado, nem faz. Certo ?

Comment: Na sua página ASP você pode verificar se ele está logado e retornar a string `true` se sim, ou `false` se não. No jquery você só verifica pelo `true` mesmo, que é quando funcionar. No else você redireciona para logar.

Comment: cara, não funcionou. :(

Comment: Qual parte não funcionou? Pode dar mais detalhes?

Comment: Não reconhece a Parte do Respose. :(

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18999/discussion-between-rodrigogq-and-erik-thiago).